# Cannot create connection from JS Plumb Endpoint which is in use by another connection

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I have set set of `DIV`s which should be connectable using `jsPlumb` (*v2.0.7*).

Each of the div elements has an `Anchor` and `Endpoint` on all of its four sides. I'm able to create connections from these endpoints by drag and drop.

[image]

**The Problem:** As soon a connection between two endpoints is established, it cannot act as a source `Endpoint` for a new "create connection" drag operation anymore. Using such used endpoint as the target of a connection, works fine though.

The configuration looks like this:

```
jsPlumbConfig = {
      PaintStyle: {
        lineWidth: 1
        outlineWidth: 5
        strokeStyle: "#FFF"
        outlineColor: "transparent"
      }
      Connector: [ "Bezier", { curviness: 69 } ]
      ConnectionsDetachable: false
      DeleteEndpointsOnDetach: false
      ReattachConnections : false
      Anchors: [ "Top", "Right", "Bottom", "Left" ]
      MaxConnections: 50
      Endpoint: [ "Rectangle" ]
      EndpointStyle : {
        paintStyle: { fillStyle:'#FFF' }
      }
}
```

The `Endpoint` options are like that:

```
endpointOptions = {
      endpoint: "Rectangle"
      maxConnections: 50
      connectionsDetachable: false
      deleteEndpointsOnDetach: false
      paintStyle: { fillStyle: "#EEE", outlineColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, -0.8)" }
      endpointHoverStyle: { fillStyle: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)" }
      isSource: true
      isTarget: true
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/v0aw81v3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by setting

```
ConnectionsDetachable: true
```

Strangely this doesn't remove existing connections from one Endpoint, but allows adding additional ones.